# Link java script with the wix drop down box

Tags: velo

I am new to Wix and in js Currently, I want to add the drop-down feature from there the user can select their country. One way to implement that by adding all country manually. But I found a js file which contains all the countries from this site https://www.wix.com/code/home/forum/community-discussion/how-do-i-add-a-drop-down-menu-with-a-list-of-countries-city I wanna know how can I add the js code with the drop-down box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple. Use something like this:

```
export const countries = [
    { value: "Afghanistan", label: "Afghanistan" },
    { value: "Albania", label: "Albania" },
    { value: "Algeria", label: "Algeria" },
    { value: "Andorra", label: "Andorra" },
    { value: "Angola", label: "Angola" },
    { value: "Antigua and Barbuda", label: "Antigua and Barbuda" },
    { value: "Argentina", label: "Argentina" },
    { value: "Armenia", label: "Armenia" },
    { value: "Australia", label: "Australia" },
    { value: "Austria", label: "Austria" },
    { value: "Azerbaijan", label: "Azerbaijan" },
    { value: "Bahamas", label: "Bahamas" },
    { value: "Bahrain", label: "Bahrain" },
    { value: "Bangladesh", label: "Bangladesh" },
    { value: "Barbados", label: "Barbados" },
    { value: "Belarus", label: "Belarus" },
    { value: "Belgium", label: "Belgium" },
    { value: "Belize", label: "Belize" },
    { value: "Benin", label: "Benin" },
    { value: "Bhutan", label: "Bhutan" },
    { value: "Bolivia", label: "Bolivia" },
    { value: "Bosnia & Herzegovina", label: "Bosnia & Herzegovina" },
    { value: "Botswana", label: "Botswana" },
    { value: "Brazil", label: "Brazil" },
    { value: "Brunei", label: "Brunei" },
    { value: "Bulgaria", label: "Bulgaria" },
    { value: "Burkina Faso", label: "Burkina Faso" },
    { value: "Burundi", label: "Burundi" },
    { value: "Cabo Verde", label: "Cabo Verde" },
    { value: "Cambodia", label: "Cambodia" },
    { value: "Cameroon", label: "Cameroon" },
    { value: "Canada", label: "Canada" },
    { value: "Central African Republic", label: "Central African Republic" },
    { value: "Chad", label: "Chad" },
    { value: "Chile", label: "Chile" },
    { value: "China", label: "China" },
    { value: "Colombia", label: "Colombia" },
    { value: "Comoros", label: "Comoros" },
    { value: "Congo", label: "Congo" },
    { value: "Costa Rica", label: "Costa Rica" },
    { value: "Croatia", label: "Croatia" },
    { value: "Cuba", label: "Cuba" },
    { value: "Cyprus", label: "Cyprus" },
    { value: "Czech Republic", label: "Czech Republic" },
    { value: "Côte d'Ivoire", label: "Côte d'Ivoire" },
    { value: "Denmark", label: "Denmark" },
    { value: "Djibouti", label: "Djibouti" },
    { value: "Dominica", label: "Dominica" },
    { value: "Dominican Republic", label: "Dominican Republic" },
    { value: "DR Congo", label: "DR Congo" },
    { value: "Ecuador", label: "Ecuador" },
    { value: "Egypt", label: "Egypt" },
    { value: "El Salvador", label: "El Salvador" },
    { value: "Equatorial Guinea", label: "Equatorial Guinea" },
    { value: "Eritrea", label: "Eritrea" },
    { value: "Estonia", label: "Estonia" },
    { value: "Ethiopia", label: "Ethiopia" },
    { value: "Fiji", label: "Fiji" },
    { value: "Finland", label: "Finland" },
    { value: "France", label: "France" },
    { value: "Gabon", label: "Gabon" },
    { value: "Gambia", label: "Gambia" },
    { value: "Georgia", label: "Georgia" },
    { value: "Germany", label: "Germany" },
    { value: "Ghana", label: "Ghana" },
    { value: "Greece", label: "Greece" },
    { value: "Grenada", label: "Grenada" },
    { value: "Guatemala", label: "Guatemala" },
    { value: "Guinea", label: "Guinea" },
    { value: "Guinea-Bissau", label: "Guinea-Bissau" },
    { value: "Guyana", label: "Guyana" },
    { value: "Haiti", label: "Haiti" },
    { value: "Holy See", label: "Holy See" },
    { value: "Honduras", label: "Honduras" },
    { value: "Hungary", label: "Hungary" },
    { value: "Iceland", label: "Iceland" },
    { value: "India", label: "India" },
    { value: "Indonesia", label: "Indonesia" },
    { value: "Iran", label: "Iran" },
    { value: "Iraq", label: "Iraq" },
    { value: "Ireland", label: "Ireland" },
    { value: "Israel", label: "Israel" },
    { value: "Italy", label: "Italy" },
    { value: "Jamaica", label: "Jamaica" },
    { value: "Japan", label: "Japan" },
    { value: "Jordan", label: "Jordan" },
    { value: "Kazakhstan", label: "Kazakhstan" },
    { value: "Kenya", label: "Kenya" },
    { value: "Kiribati", label: "Kiribati" },
    { value: "Kuwait", label: "Kuwait" },
    { value: "Kyrgyzstan", label: "Kyrgyzstan" },
    { value: "Laos", label: "Laos" },
    { value: "Latvia", label: "Latvia" },
    { value: "Lebanon", label: "Lebanon" },
    { value: "Lesotho", label: "Lesotho" },
    { value: "Liberia", label: "Liberia" },
    { value: "Libya", label: "Libya" },
    { value: "Liechtenstein", label: "Liechtenstein" },
    { value: "Lithuania", label: "Lithuania" },
    { value: "Luxembourg", label: "Luxembourg" },
    { value: "Madagascar", label: "Madagascar" },
    { value: "Malawi", label: "Malawi" },
    { value: "Malaysia", label: "Malaysia" },
    { value: "Maldives", label: "Maldives" },
    { value: "Mali", label: "Mali" },
    { value: "Malta", label: "Malta" },
    { value: "Marshall Islands", label: "Marshall Islands" },
    { value: "Mauritania", label: "Mauritania" },
    { value: "Mauritius", label: "Mauritius" },
    { value: "Mexico", label: "Mexico" },
    { value: "Micronesia", label: "Micronesia" },
    { value: "Moldova", label: "Moldova" },
    { value: "Monaco", label: "Monaco" },
    { value: "Mongolia", label: "Mongolia" },
    { value: "Montenegro", label: "Montenegro" },
    { value: "Morocco", label: "Morocco" },
    { value: "Mozambique", label: "Mozambique" },
    { value: "Myanmar", label: "Myanmar" },
    { value: "Namibia", label: "Namibia" },
    { value: "Nauru", label: "Nauru" },
    { value: "Nepal", label: "Nepal" },
    { value: "Netherlands", label: "Netherlands" },
    { value: "New Zealand", label: "New Zealand" },
    { value: "Nicaragua", label: "Nicaragua" },
    { value: "Niger", label: "Niger" },
    { value: "Nigeria", label: "Nigeria" },
    { value: "North Korea", label: "North Korea" },
    { value: "Norway", label: "Norway" },
    { value: "Oman", label: "Oman" },
    { value: "Pakistan", label: "Pakistan" },
    { value: "Palau", label: "Palau" },
    { value: "Panama", label: "Panama" },
    { value: "Papua New Guinea", label: "Papua New Guinea" },
    { value: "Paraguay", label: "Paraguay" },
    { value: "Peru", label: "Peru" },
    { value: "Philippines", label: "Philippines" },
    { value: "Poland", label: "Poland" },
    { value: "Portugal", label: "Portugal" },
    { value: "Qatar", label: "Qatar" },
    { value: "Romania", label: "Romania" },
    { value: "Russia", label: "Russia" },
    { value: "Rwanda", label: "Rwanda" },
    { value: "Saint Kitts & Nevis", label: "Saint Kitts & Nevis" },
    { value: "Saint Lucia", label: "Saint Lucia" },
    { value: "Samoa", label: "Samoa" },
    { value: "San Marino", label: "San Marino" },
    { value: "Sao Tome & Principe", label: "Sao Tome & Principe" },
    { value: "Saudi Arabia", label: "Saudi Arabia" },
    { value: "Senegal", label: "Senegal" },
    { value: "Serbia", label: "Serbia" },
    { value: "Seychelles", label: "Seychelles" },
    { value: "Sierra Leone", label: "Sierra Leone" },
    { value: "Singapore", label: "Singapore" },
    { value: "Slovakia", label: "Slovakia" },
    { value: "Slovenia", label: "Slovenia" },
    { value: "Solomon Islands", label: "Solomon Islands" },
    { value: "Somalia", label: "Somalia" },
    { value: "South Africa", label: "South Africa" },
    { value: "South Korea", label: "South Korea" },
    { value: "South Sudan", label: "South Sudan" },
    { value: "Spain", label: "Spain" },
    { value: "Sri Lanka", label: "Sri Lanka" },
    { value: "St. Vincent & Grenadines", label: "St. Vincent & Grenadines" },
    { value: "State of Palestine", label: "State of Palestine" },
    { value: "Sudan", label: "Sudan" },
    { value: "Suriname", label: "Suriname" },
    { value: "Swaziland", label: "Swaziland" },
    { value: "Sweden", label: "Sweden" },
    { value: "Switzerland", label: "Switzerland" },
    { value: "Syria", label: "Syria" },
    { value: "Tajikistan", label: "Tajikistan" },
    { value: "Tanzania", label: "Tanzania" },
    { value: "TFYR Macedonia", label: "TFYR Macedonia" },
    { value: "Thailand", label: "Thailand" },
    { value: "Timor-Leste", label: "Timor-Leste" },
    { value: "Togo", label: "Togo" },
    { value: "Tonga", label: "Tonga" },
    { value: "Trinidad and Tobago", label: "Trinidad and Tobago" },
    { value: "Tunisia", label: "Tunisia" },
    { value: "Turkey", label: "Turkey" },
    { value: "Turkmenistan", label: "Turkmenistan" },
    { value: "Tuvalu", label: "Tuvalu" },
    { value: "U.K.", label: "U.K." },
    { value: "U.S.", label: "U.S." },
    { value: "Uganda", label: "Uganda" },
    { value: "Ukraine", label: "Ukraine" },
    { value: "United Arab Emirates", label: "United Arab Emirates" },
    { value: "Uruguay", label: "Uruguay" },
    { value: "Uzbekistan", label: "Uzbekistan" },
    { value: "Vanuatu", label: "Vanuatu" },
    { value: "Venezuela", label: "Venezuela" },
    { value: "Viet Nam", label: "Viet Nam" },
    { value: "Yemen", label: "Yemen" },
    { value: "Zambia", label: "Zambia" },
    { value: "Zimbabwe", label: "Zimbabwe" }
];

$w.onReady( () => {
    $w("#dropdown1").options = countries;
} );
```